# Fetch attachement id from jira attachment python

Tags: python, list, python-jira

I am able to display the attachment from jira using python using issue.fields.attachment

> ```
> attach_list = issue.fields.attachment
> print attach_list
> print attach_list[0]
> print attach_list[1]
> ```

**Output :**

```
  [<JIRA Attachment: filename=u'test.xlsx', 
     id=u'525427', 
     mimeType=u'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'>,
   <JIRA Attachment: filename=u'test2.csv', 
     id=u'525515', 
     mimeType=u'application/vnd.ms-excel'> ]

    test.xlsx
    test2.csv
```

**how to retrieve the id from that list . In the above example, I need to retrieve 525427**

Please suggest me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just access the `id` attribute:

```
attach_list[0].id
```

If you want `id` list, use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
attach_list = issue.fields.attachment
id_list = [attach.id for attach in attach_list]
```